# How to tap on a button inside a CollectionView cell which is not visible on screen

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, xcode-ui-testing

I am working on UITests using XCode. I have multiple CollectionView cells.
When I perform Count in the collectionView it shows the certain count.
I can able to access first two cells but coming to the 3rd cell as 3(depends on device size). It says that specific button I am looking for in 3rd Cell as `exists`.

But `isHittable` is false.

Is there any way I can tap on the button on the 3rd Cell.
I have tried using the extension for `forceTapElement()` which is available online, it didn’t help.

Extension Used:

```
extension XCUIElement{
    func forceTapElement(){
        if self.isHittable{
            self.tap()
        }else{
            let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: .zero)
            coordinate.tap()
        }
    }
}
```

Tried to perform swipeUp() and access the button. it still shows `isHittable` as `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I've found is to swipe up untile the `isHittable` will be `true`.

```swift
app.collectionViews.cells.staticTexts["TEST"].tap()
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)

let collectionView = app.otherElements.collectionViews.element(boundBy: 0)
let testAds = collectionView.cells
let numberOfTestAds = testAds.count
if numberOfTestAds > 0 {
    let tester = collectionView.cells.element(boundBy: 2).buttons["ABC"]
    for _ in 0..<100 {
        guard !tester.isHittable else {
            break;
        }
        collectionView.swipeUp()
    }
}
```

Please note that the `swipeUp()` method will only move few pixels. If you want to use more comprehensive methods you can get [AutoMate](https://github.com/PGSSoft/AutoMate) library and try [`swipe(to:untilVisible:times:avoid:from:)`](https://pgssoft.github.io/AutoMate/Extensions/XCUIElement.html#/s:FE8AutoMateCSo11XCUIElement5swipeFT2toOS_14SwipeDirection12untilVisibleS0_5timesSi5avoidGSaOS_16AvoidableElement_4fromCSo15XCUIApplication_T_):

```swift
app.collectionViews.cells.staticTexts["TEST"].tap()
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)

let collectionView = app.otherElements.collectionViews.element(boundBy: 0)
let testAds = collectionView.cells
let numberOfTestAds = testAds.count
if numberOfTestAds > 0 {
    let tester = collectionView.cells.element(boundBy: 2).buttons["ABC"]
    collectionView.swipe(to: .down, untilVisible: tester)
    // or swipe max 100 times in case 10 times is not enough
    // collectionView.swipe(to: .down, untilVisible: tester, times: 100)
}
```

Comment: Thank You @Bartosz..But problem is that even if I perform swipeUp() it still shows `isHittable` as `False`

Comment: Can you share an example app with this issue? If not you can check [AutoMate test](https://github.com/PGSSoft/AutoMate/blob/master/AutoMateExample/AutoMateExampleUITests/Extensions%20tests/XCUIElementExtensionTests.swift#L162) which scrolls to the 10th cell in collection view until it will be visible (exists and hittable).

Comment: Here is the Sample Code `app.collectionViews.cells.staticTexts["TEST"].tap()
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
        let testAds = app.otherElements.collectionViews.element(boundBy: 0).cells
        let numberOfTestAds = testAds.count
        if numberOfTestAds > 0{
            let tester = app.otherElements.collectionViews.element(boundBy: 0).cells.element(boundBy: 2).buttons["ABC"]
            for _ in 0..<10{
                guard !tester.isHittable else {
                    break;
                }
                Bump.swipeUp()
            }
        } `

Comment: @user1642224. I've edited my answers. Can you check if they are working? I've changed a number of swipes (max to 100).